# How to determine if my router is causing a bottleneck in uploads?

Tags: networking, backup, router

I have a home network with a cheap-o little router with a development server and a few devices hooked up to it. I am finding that backups of my server are taking FOREVER (a week for 60gb) running backups renders my internet connection useless from any other box int he house.

I have maxed out the pipe to my house from the ISP (10down, 3up), but is there a way for me to test and see if my router is bottlenecking anything?

I feel like 60gb backups shouldn't take this long so any help would be great!

Comment: are the back-ups occuring locally on your LAN or are you backing up to a server off site (internet, WAN, VPN etc)?

Answer (score 3):

You already know that you've maxed out your bandwidth, so you know that your router ***isn't*** bottlenecking. If it was, you'd be unable to max out the bandwidth.

Assuming that you're really getting 3 megabit per second up, 60 gigaBYTES will take 45.5 hours, assuming no overhead losses. So yeah, a week for a backup is reasonable. Are you just spitting files out there, or could you look into doing some sort of compression before backing up? And/or doing some sort of differential backups for subsequent runs.

Comment: well, 44.4 (repeating) hours assuming 0 overhead and a sustained top speed, but who's counting:  (60000000/(3000/8))/3600

Comment: 1024 Mbytes in a GByte

Comment: ah, touché. ...